# OSX terminal not accepting input from simple program

Tags: macos, input, terminal

I'm using OSX terminal to compile and run my C code.

For some reason whenever I want to take input from a program using the OSX terminal, instead of allowing me to type the input (for example a string), the terminal actually takes the first line of my code as input. WEIRD!

I will show my simple program and how my output looks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(void){


    char text[100];


  printf("Type a text: \n");

    gets(text);

    printf("%s\n",text);

    return 0;

}
```

My output from terminal:

```
Type a text: 
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: How are you executing the program?

Comment: gcc " file name "

./a.out<"file name"

Answer (score 0):

`<"file name"` means take input from a file named "file name", so when you run it with `./a.out<"file name"` you're telling the shell to use the source file as input to the executing program. Run it with just `./a.out` instead.